# Significado da expressão <%# "exemplo" %>

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, aspx

Estou acostumado a ver expressões como `<%= "Olá" %>` porém me deparei com um código:

```
<asp:Image 
     id="imagemStatusDocumento" 
     runat="server" 
     ImageUrl='<%# ObtemImagem(Eval("NomeTipo")) %>' 
/>
```

Destacando a parte que importa, parte do código onde temos um Octothorpe(*HashTag*):

```
<%# ObtemImagem(Eval("NomeTipo")) %>
```

Poderiam me dizer o que faz esse *hashtag* e quando devo usá-lo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É uma forma simplificada de *data binding*, então o elemento já sabe que tem que pegar o dado disponível no modelo definido acima através do `DataSourceID`. Exemplo:

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1"
  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
  DataKeyNames="ProductID"     
  RunAt="server">

  <ItemTemplate>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Product ID:</b></td>       
        <td><%# Eval("ProductID") %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Product Name:</b></td>     
        <td><%# Eval("ProductName") %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Category ID:</b></td>      
        <td><%# Eval("CategoryID") %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Quantity Per Unit:</b></td>
        <td><%# Eval("QuantityPerUnit") %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Unit Price:</b></td>       
        <td><%# Eval("UnitPrice") %></td>
      </tr>
    </table>                 
  </ItemTemplate>                 
</asp:FormView>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/WebFormsDataBinding.cs).

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178366(v=vs.140)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).